# Subdomain in nginx with codeigniter

Tags: nginx, subdomain, codeigniter

So currently all users profile page are loaded on path https://example.com/username. i want to change that and load user profile page on https://username.example.com.

i am using nginx as web server,below is the server block i have tried

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.example.com;
    if ($host ~ "^(.*)\.example\.com$") { set $subdomain $1;}
    rewrite ^ $scheme://example.com/$subdomain$request_uri permanent;
}
```

this redirects anyone who visit *.example.com to https://example.com/username which is my controller in CodeIgniter. is there a way to keep the url as username.example.com and load serve the content from https://example.com/username

Comment: Don't attempt to do rewrites in nginx. You need to handle this in your PHP code.

Comment: @MichaelHamptop i have no idea how to do that can you share with me an example ?

Comment: We don't do programming questions here. You can ask programming questions on [so].